# typedef synonymous substitution

Tags: c++

My understanding is typedef acts as a synonym for a type, or can be used as an alias for a particular type.  Also, the simplified codes below built perfectly.  The question here is if I change the second line in the main function to :

```
Array<int>::ArrayIter<T> pa = a.begin(); // substituting back the typedef  “iterator” to its original form of ArrayIter<T>.
```

I get the following error message during compilation:

> “ArrayIter” is not a member of “Array”

But the codes compiled perfectly using the "typedef" (iterator) notation.  Why is “iterator” and ArrayIter suddenly not synonymous any more:

Reference codes below:

```
template<class T> class ArrayIter {
public:
ArrayIter(T* p) : m_p(p) {
}

private:
T* m_p;
};

template<class T> class Array {

public:
  Array(int size) throw (const char*) {
    if ( size > 0 ) {
       m_p = new T[size];
       m_size = size;
    } else {
   throw "Array: invalid array dimension";
}
  }

  // typedef and methods to support the new iterator for this class
  typedef ArrayIter<T> iterator;

  ArrayIter<T> begin() {
  return ArrayIter<T>(m_p);
  }

private:
  T* m_p;
  int m_size;
};


int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

  Array<int> a(10);
  Array<int>::iterator pa = a.begin();

 return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error says, `ArrayIter` is not a member of `Array`: it's a separate class, declared in the surrounding namespace. Therefore, `Array<int>::ArrayIter<T>` is invalid, and should just be `ArrayIter<int>`.

`iterator` *is* a member of `Array`, so `Array<int>::iterator` *is* valid, and is an alias for `ArrayIter<int>`.

Comment: Thank you Mike for all the answers.  I am a new member and really valued this site a lot.  Thank you guys!

Answer (score 0):

`ArrayIter` is not a nested class inside `Array` so `Array::ArrayIter` would be invalid declaration. `ArrayIter` is defined in global scope only, so you can `ArrayIter<int> iter = a.begin();`. The typedef `iterator` is defined inside `Array`, hence you can access it as `Array<int>::iterator`.

Answer (score 0):

`ArrayIter<T>` definitely isn't member of `Array`, how could it be, when it's declared outside?

The gap in your understanding is how scoping works.

```
class A
{
};
```

`A` is now type in global namespace. Now, let's assume second class:

```
class B
{
public:
    typedef ::A C;
};
```

`C` is defined inside of `B`, so it's full name is `B::C`. But, `A` is still in global namespace! `typedef`ing it to something doesn't change scope of original name, therefore `A` is never member of `B`, in situation like this.

To conclude - in global namespace, the following (taken from your code) are the same:

```
Array<int>::iterator pa = a.begin();
```

is the same as

```
ArrayIter<int> pa = a.begin();
```

Comment: Thank you very much Griwes for you clarifications.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any equivalence between the variants. `ArrayIter` is not a type, it is template. The typedef name `iterator` in your example refers to a specific specialization of `ArrayIter` template. Inside `Array<int>` it will refer to `ArrayIter<int>`. Inside `Array<double>` it will refer to `ArrayIter<double>`. This is exactly what you asked the compiler to do by your `typedef`.

It does not in any way bring the `ArrayIter` template into the `Array` class. It is still not a member. It still lives in the global namespace, while `Array<>::iterator` simply refers to it.

On top of that it is completely not clear what `T` are you trying to refer to inside `main`. There's no `T` there.

If you want to bring `ArrayIter` into `Array` as a template, you can use a new feature of C++11 standard, known as "template typedef" or "template alias declaration"

```
template <typename T>
class Array {
  ...
  template <typename U>  using ArrayIter = ::ArrayIter<U>;
  ...
};
```

Now you can use `Array::ArrayIter` as a template.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you said you want to "undo" the typedef. Your typedef looks like this:

```
typedef ArrayIter<T> iterator;
```

when used inside an Array[int], this "expands" to

```
typedef ArrayIter<int> iterator;
```

so, given the line

```
Array<int>::iterator pa = a.begin();
```

which uses the typedef, you can manually undo the typedef to get

```
ArrayIter<int> pa = a.begin();
```

which works just fine :-)

Basically, the typedef is named "Array[int]::iterator", not just "iterator".

Answer (score 0):

It's because your iterator is defined in the scope of `Array` while your `ArrayIter` is defined in the global scope.  To achieve what you said, you should put the `ArrayIter` inside `Array`

```
template<class T> class Array { 

public: 
    template<class T> class ArrayIter { 
    public: 
        ArrayIter(T* p) : m_p(p) { 
        } 

    private: 
        T* m_p; 
    }; 


    Array(int size) throw (const char*) { 
        if ( size > 0 ) { 
            m_p = new T[size]; 
            m_size = size; 
        } else { 
            throw "Array: invalid array dimension"; 
        } 
    } 

    // typedef and methods to support the new iterator for this class 
    typedef ArrayIter<T> iterator; 

    ArrayIter<T> begin() { 
        return ArrayIter<T>(m_p); 
    } 

private: 
    T* m_p; 
    int m_size; 
}; 


int main(int argc, char* argv[]) { 

    Array<int> a(10); 
    Array<int>::ArrayIter<int> pa = a.begin(); 

    return 0; 
}
```